# Changing encoding and charset to UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, http-headers

We need our web application to handle additional characters - and so need to move from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. So my q is UTF-8 backwards compatible with ISO-8859-1?

I have made the following changes, and can now handle all characters, but want to make sure there's no edge cases I'm missing.

1. Changed Content-Type:
   from "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
   to   "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
2. Tomcat Connector URIEncoding from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to change the text encodings and the db encodings also. For mysql, change the db collation, field collation values to utf-8 unicode ci and also while saving the ascii files, select utf-8. All the files in your application needs to be utf-8 including css, js and other files. Otherwise, your additional chars will be displayed wrong.

Comment: Thanks, checked db and it looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is UTF-8 backwards compatible with ISO-8859-1?

Unicode is a superset of the code points contained in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) so all the "characters" can be represented in UTF-8 but how they map to byte values is different. There is overlap between the encoded values but it is not 100%.

In terms of serving content or processing forms submissions you are unlikely to have many issues.

It may mean a breaking change for URL handling. For example, for a parameter value `naïve` there would be two incompatible forms:

- `http://example.com/foo?p=na%EFve`
- `http://example.com/foo?p=na%C3%AFve`

This is only likely to be an issue if there are external applications relying on the old form.